# asw-sdk-cpp initAPI and ShutDownAPI

Tags: c++, aws-sdk-cpp

There is a function that tries to upload or download.
Should we keep calling initAPI and ShutdownAPI every time we call these functions?
Or can I just call it once?

Comment: Hi @Qt.jo.ha and welcome to Stackoverflow. Can I suggest you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask? in particular, you may want to add "ASW" tag to indicate that your question is actually about ASW and not C++; You might also want to put what you tried and some example code.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call InitAPI and ShutdownAPI once.